# Lucene.net Error: read past EOF on indexWriter.Optimize function

Tags: c#

We use lucene.net version 2.0 dll for search in documents. once we publish the document, content of document is passed to lucene for indexing purpose. Everything was working fine. But now when we publish another document, it throws an error below:

```
System.IO.IOException: read past EOF
at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill()
at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte()
at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadInt()
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.ReadDeleteableFiles()
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.DeleteSegments(ArrayList segments)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MergeSegments(Int32 minSegment, Int32 end)
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.FlushRamSegments()
at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Optimize()
```

The problem is we cannot delete files created by lucene, because there are thousands of documents that need to be published again in order to recreate index. please suggest solution and/or possible reason why we are getting this error??

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(lucenePath, false);

try
{
    IndexReader ir = IndexReader.Open(lucenePath);
    ir.DeleteDocuments(new Term("id", document.Lang + "-" + document.IDDoc));
    ir.Close();
}
catch (Exception) { }

IndexWriter iwriter;
try
{
    iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, false);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true);
}
iwriter.SetMaxFieldLength(25000);
Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("content", fulltext, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("title", document.DocName, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("id", document.Lang + "-" + document.IDDoc, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
iwriter.Optimize();
iwriter.Close();
directory.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using Lucene.net 2.0 as well and have encountered an exception similar to your exception (see below). I resolved the issue by deleting the Lucene index directory, and rebuilded the directory again.

Our Error:

```
System.IO.IOException: read past EOF
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, Boolean closeDir, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, Boolean autoCommit, Int32 maxFieldLength, IndexingChain indexingChain, IndexCommit commit)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter..ctor(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, MaxFieldLength mfl)
```